# Fancybox error: prev and next areas have black background on hover

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've installed an unmolested version of Fancybox 2 on a site I'm building - it all works fine apart from when hovering over the previous, next and close areas a black background appears over the image.

The only modifications I have made to the standard Fancybox are controls for the fadein speeds etc

You can see the page [here](http://www.alexandermicklewright.com/pictures/)

If you click on any of the images, the you will see the issue when hovering over the next / prev / close buttons.

I've used this on another site and haven't had this problem, so can't see what the issue is.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not a fancybox error but a user-generated behavior.

That black area is actually a link within fancybox to move to the next/prev elements of the gallery and becomes black because you have this CSS rule (line 25) in your [style.css](http://www.alexandermicklewright.com/_css/style.css) file :

```
a:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Generally speaking it's not a good idea to apply general CSS rules to tag elements because they will affect the whole site (as it does in this case), use specificity instead like :

```
#parent_container a:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

or

```
a.this_class:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Its a glaringly obvious mistake now!
Thanks again